# Dots following the path

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, caanimation

I am looking for some simple method that will animate dots moving by closed path.

I have some path created with UIBezierPath. Which is represented by CAShapeLayer.

I want to place on this shape dots that will move around this closed path. The problem is that I couldn't find the best method. I do not want to add every dot programmatically. Maybe there is some method where could be use particles.

Path will have different shapes. The most important thing is to please dots with the same distance between each other.

I will be glad for help

Comment: Have you tried a `CAKeypathAnimation`?

Comment: What have you tried? CAShapeLayer has a *.lineDashPattern* property. What if you set it to `myShapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [1 3]` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example you can run in playground.

It's based on an article by Matt Long (from a while back) http://www.cimgf.com/2009/10/20/marching-ants-with-core-animation/

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 700))

container.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

let shp = CAShapeLayer()
shp.bounds = v.bounds
let pth = UIBezierPath()
pth.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 220))
pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 40))
pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 80))
pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 40))
pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 40))
pth.close()
shp.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
shp.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
shp.lineWidth = 3.0

shp.lineDashPattern = [5, 5]

shp.path = pth.cgPath
shp.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)
v.layer.addSublayer(shp)

container.addSubview(v)

let dashAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
dashAnim.fromValue = 0
dashAnim.toValue = 15
dashAnim.duration = 0.75
dashAnim.repeatCount = 10000

shp.add(dashAnim, forKey: "lineDashPhase")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```